# ASP.NET Core MVC 6 jQuery Validation not working on AJAX Post

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ajax

I am dynamically creating create/update form on a bootstrap popup model using AJAX. When a user clicks, add or edit, a model will be visible with the create/update form. I want to do a jQuery validation when user clicks submit. If a form is valid, then it would perform AJAX post.

The jQuery `("#userForm").valid()` is always returning true, even if the required fields condition is not satisfied. What am I missing?

My view looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "userForm", name = "userForm"}))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="Name">Name*</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @id = "txtName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name"})
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })              
        </div>
        <div class="col-12  mt-5">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="Description">More Info</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @style = "width: 100%; height: 200px;",@class="form-control" })
          
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 text-center">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save" id="btnSubmit" onclick="saveData()" />
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel"/>
            </div>                
        </div>
       
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model=>Model.Id,new { @id = "pId"})
    }
```

My view model looks like this

```
public class DataEntryViewModel
{
        public int Id{get;set;}
        [Required, Remote("NameAlreadyExists", "Home", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Name already exists.")]
        public string Name { get; set; } //Name is unique
      
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My jQuery method looks like this

```
function saveData()
{
    if ($("#userForm").valid()) { //check if form is valid using model annotation
        
        $('#userForm').submit();
    }
    else {
       
        return false;
    }

    $("#userForm").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Success! ' + JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('Error!');
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        })
    });
}
```

I have referenced jQuery validation and unobtrusive validation as

```
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Hi @WorkInProgress, Do you mean when you don't input any data into `Name` input textbox and click submit button, Then form will not show any error message just submit directly? I just copy and test your code, The error message can show correctly as expected, I don't find error in the code you provided. BTW, After you validate the data, Do you want to disable the button and use ajax to send the request? why do you just use submit() to submit directly? In my opinion, you can Encapsulate the following ajax code into a method, then call this method after validate success.